# Merge rows in Pandas Dataframe with specific rules on how to handle each column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe with meaningless index that contains rows in which one of the columns can be repeated. Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file1.txt'],
    'size': ['52', '41', '32', '55'],
    'attempts': [4, 4, 3, 1]
})

        file size  attempts
0  file1.txt   52         4
1  file2.txt   41         4
2  file3.txt   32         3
3  file1.txt   55         1
```

I want to get rid of duplicates, but not just deleting them. I'd like to keep just one row per different 'file', that the 'size' column becomes the maximum all the repeated elements, and that the 'attempts' column becomes the sum of repeated 'attempts'. In other words, I'd like to get:

```
        file size  attempts
0  file1.txt   55         5
1  file2.txt   41         4
2  file3.txt   32         3
```

I know how to do this explicitly looping through the Dataframe, but I'd like to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to aggregate with `size` using `max` value and `attempts` using `sum` on the attempt counts.

```
df.groupby('file', as_index=False).agg({'size': 'max', 'attempts': 'sum'})
```

Result:

```
        file size  attempts
0  file1.txt   55         5
1  file2.txt   41         4
2  file3.txt   32         3
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and accurate reply. And how to cope with other columns that are present but are just equal? How can I just discard the elements in these trivial columns?

Comment: @Onturenio You want to discard some columns not shown in the sample data ?  If yes, you can use  `df.drop()` and list the columns in the parameter `columns=`  e.g. `df.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2'])`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. What I wanted was to keep the columns, but arbitrarily selecting one of the repeated items (along the rows). To try luck, I just tried intuitively `last` as the function to use in these columns and it worked as one would expect. This people developing Pandas know what they are doing :)

Comment: @Onturenio  Great that you found the solution for the extended steps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very dirty solution, but nonetheless should work:

```
df_ = df.groupby('file').max('size')
df_ = pd.concat([df_.iloc[:,0], df.groupby('file').sum('attempts')['attempts']], axis=1)

df_

           size     attempts
file        
file1.txt   55         5
file2.txt   41         4
file3.txt   32         3
```